# TomCat server configuration not appearing in Intelliji

Tags: java, tomcat, intellij-idea, remote-debugging

im trying to set up remote debugging in a tom cat server i have already running. The problem i have is that when i try to edit the run configuration tomcat server is not an option in Intelliji.  Here are some images to demo clearly my issue:

[image]

UPDATE: AFTER Creating a debug configuration now im getting the following error:
[image]

i also checked the first line of my running servers log statment and it showed its running on 8081:

```
Listening for transport dt_socket at address: 8081
```

Here is my intelliji debug configuration:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add usual remote debug configuration as shown below (you should specify port). And i suppose you run tomcat in `jpda` mode.
[image]

EDIT:

For enable [JPDA](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Platform_Debugger_Architecture) debugger run tomcat with command below:

`catalina.sh jpda run` 
or
`catalina.sh jpda start`

you can check port number in catalina.sh, for example tomcat 7.0.27

```
if [ "$1" = "jpda" ] ; then
  if [ -z "$JPDA_TRANSPORT" ]; then
    JPDA_TRANSPORT="dt_socket"
  fi
  if [ -z "$JPDA_ADDRESS" ]; then
    JPDA_ADDRESS="8000"
  fi
  if [ -z "$JPDA_SUSPEND" ]; then
    JPDA_SUSPEND="n"
  fi
  if [ -z "$JPDA_OPTS" ]; then
    JPDA_OPTS="-agentlib:jdwp=transport=$JPDA_TRANSPORT,address=$JPDA_ADDRESS,server=y,suspend=$JPDA_SUSPEND"
  fi
  CATALINA_OPTS="$CATALINA_OPTS $JPDA_OPTS"
  shift
fi
```

as you can see in script, it add exactly the same command line arguments as on screenshot.

If you are using Windows, replace script name with catalina.bat

Comment: im not sure how to update to jpda mode ? how can i confirm what mode my servers running in and send to you ?